# How do I change the formatting for my return values in this function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, set-returning-functions

I have a function I created like this:

```
create or replace function core.nrt_summary_by_param_id(int) returns table (reason_type_id int, reason_id int, descr varchar(256), num int, pct numeric, cause_rank int) as $$
begin
    return query
        with r3 as (
            //A bunch of queries
        )
        select
            r3.reason_type_id,
            r3.reason_id, 
            r3.desc, 
            r3.num, 
            r3.pct,
            r3.cause_rank
        from r3;
        where
            r3.param_id = $1
    return;
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

When I call the function like so:

```
select nrt_summary_by_param_id(5);
```

The results are like this:

```
              nrt_summary_by_param_id  
----------------------------------------------------  
 (1,2001,"A",14,19.72,1)  
 (1,2006,"B",9,12.68,2)
 (1,2202,"C",8,11.27,3)
 (1,2002,"D",8,11.27,3)
 (1,2302,"E",7,9.86,5)
 (1,2201,"F",4,5.63,6)
 (1,2206,"G",4,5.63,6)
 (1,2301,"H",2,2.82,8)
 (1,2303,"I",2,2.82,8)
 (1,2005,"J",2,2.82,8)
 (1,2004,"K",2,2.82,8)
 (1,2204,"L",2,2.82,8)
 (,,"M",7,9.87,11)
 (13 rows)
```

How do I get the return from my function as a table with more than one column? How do I get each of the individual columns to show up? I would like the return to be like if the whole query that's inside the function was executed normally from the command line. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function is return a table then you should treat it like a table. How do we normally look at tables in SQL? We SELECT ... FROM them. You're looking for something more like this:

```
select ...
from nrt_summary_by_param_id(5);
```

Comment: @DiZou: If you didn't get the subtle hint: Start with `SELECT * FROM nrt_summary_by_param_id(5);`